# what's wrong with my lua code?

Tags: lua

```
local consumer = coroutine.create(function(i)
   while true do
    i = i - 1
    print('consumer: ' .. i)
    coroutine.yield(i)
   end
end)

local producer = coroutine.create(function()
   while true do
     i = i or 0
     i = i + 1
     print('producer: ' .. i)
     status, value = coroutine.resume(consumer, i)
     i = value
   end
end)

coroutine.resume(producer)
```

[image: the console print like this]

but it's completely wrong, the right print should be like this:
0 1 0 1 01

Comment: Replace `coroutine.yield(i)` with `i = coroutine.yield(i)` in consumer.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Please write this as an answer so it can be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace coroutine.yield(i) with i = coroutine.yield(i) in consumer.
@EgorSkriptunoff thanks for help